# It's possible disable ssl validation from ansible.cfg for Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I would like to disable SSL validation from the *ansible.cfg* configuration file.

Something similar that exists in the [`get_url` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html), but from the Ansible configuration file.

```yaml
parameter : validate_certs: no
```

Example:

```yaml
- name: Download JBoss without proxy
  get_url:
    url: "{{jboss_eap_7_3_4_download_url}}"
    url_username: "{{repo_user}}"
    url_password: "{{repo_token}}"
    dest: "{{jboss_archive}}"
    validate_certs: no        
#   ^-- something similar to this parameter
  when: proxy is not defined or proxy == None
```

Comment: Use HTTP, if you do not need security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot disable certification validation for all your tasks in ansible.cfg. This is because ansible.cfg is for configuring Ansible and each module has its own way of establishing HTTP connections.

You could however use [module_defaults](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_module_defaults.html) to have `validate_certs: false` be applied to all `get_url` tasks.