# ansible issue with self signed certificate

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I encountered this Ansible problem because the task's URL was an HTTPS request with a self signed certificate.
Is it possible to disable SSL validation from ansible.cfg for Ansible?

The task

```yaml
- name: "Spark: fetch source"
  get_url:
    url: "{{ spark_download_url }}"
    dest: "/usr/local/src/{{ spark_bin_name }}"
```

Causes the error

> fatal: [app]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "dest": "/usr/bin/",
> "elapsed": 0, "gid": 0, "group": "root", "mode": "0555", "msg":
> "Request failed: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
> certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:897)>", "owner": "root", "size":
> 36864, "state": "directory", "uid": 0, "url":
> "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/packages/XXXX/mXXXc"}

Comment: Does this answer you question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69614920/its-possible-disable-ssl-validation-from-ansible-cfg-for-ansible/69631534#69631534?

Comment: there are no method exists for adding to a globle file. ansible.cfg  or before runnung playbook